# Determine whether Array 1 contains all values from Array 2

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays which might look something like this:

```
$a1 = array('c','b','a');
$a2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
```

I need to somehow check whether every value in `$a1` is present in `$a2`.

I've looked at `array_diff` and `array_intersect` but can't see how they can be used because the only return the values that are present and not present respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "present respectively" but array_diff is the function you are looking for. Just make sure you pass the arrays into the function in the correct order. Try:

```
// result = no
echo count( array_diff( $a1, $a2 ) ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
// result = yes
echo count( array_diff( $a2, $a1 ) ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! I guess I was passing them in the wrong order when I first tried it

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php

Okay, I'll make it clearer:

The Function in_array() gives you a Boolean if the needle is in the haystack.
So, a line like this will work for you:

```
$return = in_array($a1, $a2, true);
```

If `$a1` is in `$a2` the function returns true, otherwise false. The third Parameter activates strict search, so there won't be return even when a false would be right.

Comment: Since PHP 4.2 in_array() takes array for all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
sizeof(array_intersect($a1, $a2)) == sizeof($a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function has_all_values($base, $comparing) {
    foreach($comparing as $value) {
        if(!in_array($base, $value))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```